# How to apply recurring pattern regex in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to use the following regex `(.+?)\1+` which works perfectly on [regexr](https://regexr.com/57r9q)

[image]

and yet when I try to find it using the `re` module, I don't get anything from the `re.search` action.

```py
>>> re.search("1", "1")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> re.search("(.+?)\1+", "111111")
>>>
```

Why doesn't this regex work in python?

Comment: `re.search(r"(.+?)\1+", "111111")` note raw string so that `\1` doesn't get converted into chr(1)

Comment: oh, never knew about that, and it worked, thanks! @Nick

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below line:

```
re.search(r"(.+?)\1+", "111111")
```